# What are CocoaPods in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Please can anyone elaborate what are **CocoaPods** in `iOS development`. I cant seem to get the idea what they are.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at [http://cocoapods.org/](http://cocoapods.org/)?

Comment: it says how to make it but doesnt state what they are...

Comment: Something that is good for beginners but no developer actually needs. However, it's a nice reference implementation for many things.

Comment: @Sulthan : Why is that so ?

Comment: @Sulthan PODs are a great why, even for experienced Developers, to integrate with third party libraries. CocoaPods will make installing and updating libraries easy, speed up compile time and let you focus on your code more.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

CocoaPods is among the best thing that I have found in recent iOS app development.
I use it to get latest Github open source project as framework and lib into my project.
The best part is it will manage dependency lib automatically so there is no need to drag and drop file and download each on folder blaa blaaa
just one simple code '`pod install` that is it ! rest will be done by Cocoa-pods
believe me it will save you hr of development time and your code will look clean and upto-date :)

If someone need to know how to install Cocoapod
just type this in your terminal

> sudo gem install cocoapods

and then make a PodFile ( plane text file ) like in folder where your project is in.

```
platform :ios, 5.0
pod 'RestKit'
```

then finally on terminal

> pod install

Then see the magic :)